# tomcat/mod_jk- error trying to configure mod_jk with tomcat+apache web server

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

I am trying to configure mod_jk so that http://domain.com/ is served by Apache while http://app.domain.com/ is served by Tomcat. Now when I go to app.domain.com, I can see Tomcat message, however I am unable to access Tomcat Manager- is there something wrong with my config in Mod JK or is it something else?

I have successfully created virtual host for app.domain.com in Tomcat Host Manager.

I was also able to create manager for app.domain.com (when I created the virtual host for app.domain.com), later I made the following changes to configure mod_jk--

```
vi /usr/local/apache/conf/vhosts.conf
```

To this file I added directives for JKMount to the VirtualHost element corresponding to our app's domain- 
    JkMount /*.* tomcat
    JkMount /*.jsp tomcat
    JkMount /servlet/* tomcat

In /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

add following---

```
##
#Directives for Mod_JK
##
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
   JkWorkersFile /usr/local/apache/conf/workers.properties
   JkShmFile     /usr/local/apache/mod_jk.shm
   JkLogFile     /usr/local/apache/mod_jk.log
   JkLogLevel    warn
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
   JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURIProxy -ForwardDirectories
</IfModule>
```

I also made changes to workers.properties to add a worker corresponding to the worker 'tomcat' i have defined above.

How do I resolve this? I was able to access Tomcat Manager for app.domain.com before I made the above changes, but I cant figure out what I did wrong/missed?